# How to create beat by multiplying square wave with tone?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, synthesizer

See the code below.  How I understand things:

- `beat` is a square wave oscillating between -1 and 1.
- Connecting `beat` to `multiplier.gain` adds the square wave of `beat` to the default gain of 1.  The result is a gain that oscillates between 0 and 2.
- As `tone` is connected to `multiplier`, I expect to hear a tone of 440Hz for two seconds, then a pause for two seconds, then the tone again, and so on.

However, where I expect the gain to be 0, I still hear a tone, only muted. *What am I doing wrong?*

I tested with Chrome 74 and Firefox 66, both on Windows 10.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script>
  var context = new window.AudioContext();
  var tone = context.createOscillator();

  var beat = context.createOscillator();
  beat.frequency.value = 0.25;
  beat.type = "square";

  var multiplier = context.createGain();
  tone.connect(multiplier);
  beat.connect(multiplier.gain);
  multiplier.connect(context.destination);

  tone.start();
  beat.start();
</script>
<button onclick="context.resume()">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the 'square' type doesn't really oscillate between -1 and 1. The range is more or less from -0.848 to 0.848. Setting the GainNode's gain AudioParam to this value should work.

```
multiplier.gain.value = 0.848;
```

To see the actual output of an oscillator you could for example use [Canopy](https://hoch.github.io/canopy/). It can run Web Audio code and then visualizes the results.

If you do for example execute the following snippet, it will show you the corresponding waveform.

```
var osc = new OscillatorNode(context);

osc.type = "square";

osc.connect(context.destination);
osc.start();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain the number 0.848? (or point to an explanation) I guess it's not just something random.

Comment: Oscillators are bandlimited and also somehow normalized as I have just learned. But I'm afraid that I don't have a simple explanation for the value.

Comment: That "magic" number is computed in https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#waveform-normalization.  You can disable it, but the ringing from the band-limited oscillator is still there. The dynamic range will be greater than 1, but that's probably not important here.